# missing factor level in R

Tags: r

I have a factor column, and I get a missing level, why R creates this missing level?

```
d0s$y
 [1] E E E E E E G G G G G G G P P P P P P P
Levels:  E G P

levels(d0s$y)
[1] ""  "E" "G" "P"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that there are blanks `""` in the dataset before subsetting.  One way would be to call `droplevels` to remove the unused levels

```
d0s$y <- droplevels(d0s$y)
```

Or call `factor` again

```
d0s$y <- factor(d0s$y)
```

---

However, it can be also be that the `""` elements are already there but because it is a `factor` the print option doesn't show it

```
y1 <- factor(rep(c("E", "G", "P", ""), each = 3))
y1
#[1] E E E G G G P P P      
#Levels:  E G P
levels(y1)
#[1] ""  "E" "G" "P"
```

Suppose, if we subset the 'y1'

```
 y2 <- y1[y1 %in% c("E", "G", "P")]
 levels(y2) #the unused levels are still there
 #[1] ""  "E" "G" "P"
```

unless we drop those levels

```
 levels(droplevels(y2))
 #[1] "E" "G" "P"
```